# how to play another video after finishing one video as video names are selected by user in a uipickerview

Tags: ios5, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

My objective is to put video files in a `uipicker`. I have added my video files names in an array and successfully extracting video file name and extensions but now my target is when user taps on row of picker then that selected video from the array will be passed to `mpmovieplayercontroller` object then that will play movie please let me know how can I write code to play another selected file after completion of one file i.e.in 1mpmovieplaybackfinished`

My code to play single video file is below.

Just let me know how can i play another video from an array:

```
-(IBAction)play:(id)sender
{
for (i = 0;i<[arrayofvideo count];i++) {<br /> NSLog(@"%d",i);

NSString *fullFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrayofvideo objectAtIndex:i]];
NSString *filename = [fullFileName stringByDeletingPathExtension];

NSLog(@"%@",filename);
NSString *extension = [fullFileName pathExtension];
NSLog(@"%@",extension);


NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
pathForResource:@"filename"
ofType:@"extension"]];
movieplayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:url];
movieplayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
movieplayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;

movieplayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,300,400);
[self.view addSubview:movieplayer.view];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
addObserver:self
selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:)
name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
object:movieplayer];

//---play movie---
[movieplayer play];
}



-(void)movieFinishedCallback:(NSNotification*) aNotification 
{
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [aNotification object];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
removeObserver:self
name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
object:player];
[player stop];
// self.view removeFromSuperView;
[self.view removeFromSuperview];

//call the play button again
// pls tell me what to write here to call play function

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to restructure your code.

The code you posted builds a pathname from your array of video pathnames, and then uses a fixed filename of @"filename". That's not right.

You should write a method "playFileAtIndex" that finds a filename at a specific index and plays that file. I would suggest adding a BOOL parameter playMultipleVideos to the method. If the flag is true, the method would set up a movieFinishedCallback to increment the index and start the next movie playing.

Then make your button IBAction method set an index iVar to the selected row and invoke the playFileAtIndex method.